# Excel merge duplicate columns and remove unduplicate columns

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have 3 columns in excel and want to 1. Merge duplicate columns based in another column.
2. Remove cells that don't fall within the duplicated columns.

column A
10
11
12
13

Column B
L
M
N
P
Q

Column C
M
N

Required Output
Column A  | Column B | Column C
 11                       M                  M
12                  N                 N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a helper column to identify the rows not appearing in column C, for example, in column D, use the formula:

```
=MATCH(B1, C:C, 0)
```

And drag the formula to the last cell in column B that contains a value.

Insert a filter and filter on only the `#N/A`. Select the data cells in columns A and B and then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> (this selects only the visible cells; it's safer).

Delete all those cells opting for 'Shift cells up'.

---

If you don't want a helper column, you can make use of conditional formatting. Select A1 and then columns A and B (Make sure that A1 remains the active cell). In conditional formatting with formula, input:

```
=ISNA(MATCH($B1, C:C, 0))
```

And pick a formatting; for example yellow.

Click OK a couple of times and all the cells to be removed will be highlighted. Then repeat what I described as from inserting a filter, but this time, filter on the coloured cells.